# Processing a Broadcast in a background thread

Tags: android, android-asynctask, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast, kotlin-coroutines

I was reading up on `Broadcast receivers` in the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts#effects-process-state) and came across moving `Broadcasts` to a background thread using `goAsync()` to flag that the `Broadcast receiver`  needs more time to finish after `onReceive()` is complete.

Now, `Broadcast receivers` are allowed to run for up to 10 seconds before the system will consider them non-responsive and while we can use `goAsync()` to move it off the main thread, I learnt that **the broadcast execution limit still applies**, My question is since the aim is to move it off the `Main thread`, can we make use of `Coroutines` in the `onReceive()` considering that the `AsyncTask` API has/will be deprecated in Android 11? Also, will it be bounded by the 10 seconds execution limit?

I would really appreciate any response or corrections to errors I made while framing this question.

Comment: It doesn't matter what API you use to offload your work from the main thread, as long as your app is in the background (you don't have an open activity or foreground service) system will terminate your apps process in short period of time and nothing can survive it.

Comment: Try using JobScheduler to offload the long-running work.

Comment: @Pawel alright, thank you.